# jquery disable prev next button modal image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change button css prev and next when is in first child and last child.

I was thinking about this code but not success :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //begin open modal
  var $thisImage;
  $('.container img').click(function() {
    $thisImage = $(this);
    var src = $thisImage.attr('src');
    $('.modal').css({
      display: "block"
    });
    $('.modal-content').attr("src", src);
  });
  //begin navigate modal
  function navprev() {
    if ($thisImage.prev().is('img')) {
      var prev = $thisImage.prev().attr('src');
      var first = $thisImage.first().attr('src');
      $thisImage = $thisImage.prev();
      $('.modal-content').attr("src", prev);
      if ($('.modal-content').attr("src", first)) {
        $('.prev').css("background", "red")
      }
    }
  }

  function navnext() {
    if ($thisImage.next().is('img')) {
      var next = $thisImage.next().attr('src');
      $thisImage = $thisImage.next();
      $('.modal-content').attr("src", next);
    }
  }
  //prev
  $('.prev').click(function() {
    navprev();
  });
  //next    
  $('.next').click(function() {
    navnext();
  });
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.modal').css({
      display: "none"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container img {
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 170px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.prev, .next {
  background: blue;
}
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 70px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/287" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/285" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/286" alt="" />
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal">
    <button class="prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
    <br>
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <img src="" class="modal-content" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

My goals are:

1. When i click `prev` until first element it will change css rule of button element, to add disable effect.
2. Same as `prev`, but it for `next` button

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/akhid1000/26ga46uy/1/)

Comment: You can add attribute `disabled` so you not need to take care about the style and the click event.

Comment: @MoshFeu how to do attr disable?

Comment: You can read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`disabled`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) attribute so you earn to points:

1. Button's style will change and will seen not clickable.
2. Button will not clickable.

**Note:** You can style the disabled button as you wish using `button[disabled]` selector in the css.

Now, to the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //begin open modal
  var $thisImage;
  $('.container img').click(function() {
    $thisImage = $(this);
    var src = $thisImage.attr('src');
    $('.modal').css({
      display: "block"
    });

    initButtons();

    $('.modal-content').attr("src", src);
  });

  //begin navigate modal
  function navprev() {
    console.log($thisImage.prev());

    var prev = $thisImage.prev().attr('src');
    var first = $thisImage.first().attr('src');
    $thisImage = $thisImage.prev();
    $('.modal-content').attr("src", prev);
  }

  function navnext() {
    if ($thisImage.next().is('img')) {
      var next = $thisImage.next().attr('src');
      $thisImage = $thisImage.next();
      $('.modal-content').attr("src", next);
    }
  }

  function initButtons() {
    $('.next').prop('disabled', !$thisImage.next().is('img'))
    $('.prev').prop('disabled', !$thisImage.prev().is('img'))
  }

  //prev
  $('.prev').click(function() {
    navprev();
    initButtons();
  });
  //next    
  $('.next').click(function() {
    navnext();
    initButtons();
  });
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.modal').css({
      display: "none"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container img {
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 170px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 70px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/287" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/285" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/286" alt="" />
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal">
    <button class="prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
    <br>
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <img src="" class="modal-content" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/bezujo/edit?html,css,js

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the previous button, I think you can do the next now ;)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //begin open modal
  var $thisImage;
  $('.container img').click(function() {
    $thisImage = $(this);
    var src = $thisImage.attr('src');
    $('.modal').css({
      display: "block"
    });
    if ($thisImage.prev().is('img')) {
      $('.prev').css("background", "blue");
    } else {
      $('.prev').css("background", "red");
    }

    $('.modal-content').attr("src", src);
  });
  //begin navigate modal
  function navprev() {
    console.log($thisImage.prev());

    var prev = $thisImage.prev().attr('src');
    var first = $thisImage.first().attr('src');
    $thisImage = $thisImage.prev();
    $('.modal-content').attr("src", prev);
    $('.prev').css("background", "blue");
    if ($thisImage.prev().is('img')) {
        $('.prev').css("background", "blue")
    } else {
      $('.prev').css("background", "red")
    }
  }

  function navnext() {
    if ($thisImage.next().is('img')) {
      var next = $thisImage.next().attr('src');
      $thisImage = $thisImage.next();
      $('.modal-content').attr("src", next);
    }
  }
  //prev
  $('.prev').click(function() {
    navprev();
  });
  //next    
  $('.next').click(function() {
    navnext();
  });
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.modal').css({
      display: "none"
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hc05jsqe/